# What are the options for showing clients their proofs online?

Tags: software, web, photo-galleries

I'm looking for a solution to show clients their photo proofs online.  I would like something that can integrate with my website, meaning basically I just want to host it on my site so I can use the domain.

I don't need any purchasing ability, it would be ideal for them to be able to select their images and hit submit, where I receive an email of which ones they choose.

I'm looking for a simple solution, something that allows for easy content management.  Something like the way Dropbox works - i.e. - I have a Dropbox folder on my computer, and can manage all files in it very quickly and easily, having everything upload and update automatically.

What type of solutions are you guys using for showing your clients their proofs?  I'm looking to evolve from emailing a .zip file and saying pick what you like.

Thanks!

Comment: "Something like the way Dropbox works" = I think you already have your answer. FYI, clients aren't hung up on the domain you use to show them the photos. They just want something easy to use.

Comment: H&H color lab offers image hosting from your own domain, I think its about $30 a month +commission because it does allow for online orders.

Comment: Did you have a look at this question http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12497/what-solutions-are-available-for-a-self-hosted-portfolio-website ? Or http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/7512/7271 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try to Piwigo http://piwigo.org + plugin User Collections. Once your client has finished his selection, you can see it live in the gallery!

Piwigo is a free and open source software, you can download it and install it on your own website.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.instaproofs.com charges a sliding fee up to 15% of the order.  If you're doing low volume, that might be a solution to collect credit card payment and for clients to view.  I like the instaproofs model because I control the final product.  I don't like the idea of outsourcing the printing without an intermediate step by myself to finish the proofs.  I don't want to finish *all* proofs.