# What is a Picasa alternative for posting to a website?

Tags: web, tagging, picasa, software-recommendation

My love/hate relationship with Picasa just permanently tipped to hate I'm afraid.  For no reason I can discern Picasa decided I didn't ***really*** mean to add yesterday's photos to [an album](https://plus.google.com/photos/111471664614886058938/albums/5694235458707286625) and right in front of my eyes they disappeared.  I don't want to waste any more time with Quirky Picasa.

What PC / web software is good for posting reduced-size (1600 pixels max width), tagged pix to the web? Cameras include iPhone (jpeg) and Canon DSLRs (jpeg & raw).  The site's goals include:

- Family & friends should be able to see the photos I've added since their last visit, as well as show a guest the photos tagged "Aunt Gurty".
- People should be able to contact me to use photos for commercial purposes.

Comment: Picasa is one of the *very* few things that is *both* a software organization and a sharing service.  If you break out of picasa, you'll need to separate those functions and separately we have those two questions answered very well.

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/295/what-are-the-best-sites-to-share-photo-galleries-with-friends for sharing

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/what-software-is-focused-on-reviewing-and-organizing-images for organization

Comment: I'm not sure if linking to four of your own images is really necessary here. Sorry but that just seems like blatant advertising to me.

Comment: @rfusca - Thanks. I thought this must have been discussed.

Comment: @dpollitt - Understood. But my posted question (my first btw) had "Noob" in the title and something like "This seems like it should a FAQ but I can't find it" in the text. I tried to make it obvious I'm new to posting questions here. The _edited_ question makes me look like a self-promoting jerk. No big deal, just a suggestion to use care cropping a question to not lose its composition.  :)

Comment: @MarkJerde - The edit just revised the title for clarity and removed the unnecessary links to pictures. Stack Exchange is a collaboratively edited site, and as such your answers and questions will be editing quite often! Check out the FAQ if you have any questions - http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#editing

Comment: @MarkJerde I'm not sure what you mean by the question losing its composition. It shouldn't have "noob" in the title if that is what you are suggesting. Did I edit the original question you had in mind out? Sorry if so, please correct me.

Comment: If you want to try some other software you can use iPhoto or Aperture. Lightroom is a very good software as mentioned here. But if you are not happy with Lightroom you can try those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lightroom is a great app for organisation and workflow and from version 3 you can set up your Flickr, Smugmug/Facebook, whatever sharing accounts, and post directly from within Lightroom once you're happy with your photo :-)

EDIT: [Lightroom features website](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/features/) -- has a little video on there of publishing photos to external service.  Flickr would also give you your ability to restrict access and use tags as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Webshots. You can decide if you want to make a photo/album personal or public. I haven't used if for a while, but am considering starting using it again.
It also has other features that may be of interest (pro photos to view or buy, e-cards etc, and a desktop/screensaver software that you can link to your account)